# 2nd set of VB script is running first than the first set of statements

Tags: vba

I have 2 sets of VB scripts, one is to create a file and 2nd is to rename the file.

When I am running it, it is giving me error: 'file not found promoting error line at move command', which means it is looking for file to rename. But I want to generate a file and then rename.

When I am running individually it's working fine. Can someone please assist to resolve the issue?

**Set1:**

```
' it will create a object called Export.tar.gz  (Working fine - Due to security contrarian i have partially placed the code in set1)

Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.shell")

objShell.run "cmd /C CD D:\test\VB practice\Mrcctl ************************************ localfolder=D:\FullExport"
Set objShell = Nothing
```

**Set2:**

```
Dim ObjFSO
SET ObjFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim file1, file2

file1 = "D:\FullExport\Export.tar.gz"
file2 = "D:\FullExport\Export" & year(date) & month(date) & Day(Date) & ".tar.gz"

ObjFSO.MoveFile file1, file2

Set ObjFSO = Nothing
```

Comment: A few things to start with, add the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` to your Project References (Tools-->References) to be able to early-bind the FSO. Then declare all your variables properly, `dim file1 as String` and `dim ObjFSO as FileSystemObject` to get the full benefits of InteliSense. Also, can you write where the error happens and what the values of the variables are at this point? (View-->Locals Window)

Comment: Just to clarify It is a VBS script.

The error is file not found pointing to line (ObjFSO.MoveFile file1, file2) and Char1

Answer (score 0):

The shell command is running in a separate system thread, therefore VBS script will not wait when shell is finished. To solve this problem, you need to wait until the file is actually created and released by the system and only then rename it.
As a possible solution, you could update your 2nd script as follows:

**Set2**

```
Dim ObjFSO
SET ObjFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim file1, file2

file1 = "D:\FullExport\Export.tar.gz"
file2 = "D:\FullExport\Export" & year(date) & month(date) & Day(Date) & ".tar.gz"

On Error Resume Next
Do
    Err.Clear
    Set oFile = ObjFSO.OpenTextFile(file1, 8, False)
    if err.number = 0 then Exit Do

    WScript.Sleep 1000
Loop

On Error Goto 0
oFile.Close
set oFile = Nothing

ObjFSO.MoveFile file1, file2

Set ObjFSO = Nothing
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for input.

now only first set is running ,i Dn't see the 2ed set renaming the file.

Comment: No, it's just running the 1 st set and switching off

Comment: Can you please share your final full script, combining 1st and 2nd sets?